# Assets outside activity

Tags: android, android-activity, assets, android-context

I need to open ad asset file from a class, different by activity.
I think I could pass the main context (or activity) by parameters to this class, but I want to know if there are easier ways.

Answer (score 1):

Passing the Activity's Context to discrete classes is something I do on a regular basis. I normally pass it to the constructor and store it as an instance variable...

```
public MyClass {

    private Context parentContext = null;

    public MyClass(Context context) {

        parentContext = context;

    }
}
```

When instantiating the class from an Activity, I just pass `this` for the context parameter of the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If the class is a dialog or a view subclass - you can call getContext() from it. Otherwise, you have to pass the Context there somehow, either as a parameter or as a class variable, initialized duting contruction. In the latter case, sometimes it makes sense to derive your class from ContextWrapper.